Why are there so many denominations of Christianity?
How can there be so many denominations of Christianity? Christianity is solely based on the Bible, so how can multiple faiths come from it?

related, possible duplicate: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/74835/22319

It is an excellent question!  The truth is that Christianity is a faith, not a religion, but because man wants to take some of the credit for their salvation, they adhere to "doctrines of men" (Col 2:18-23) to bring glory to themselves, overshadowing the only glory that matters which is of God (Jesus Christ crucified).  It was not supposed to be about what man does for God (through religion), but what God did for man through Jesus Christ. Christ crucified should have been the end of religion and the beginning of faith alone in Him and His completed work for mankind.

Welcome to C.SE and thank you for your question.
The answer is a combination of:

Human failure/sin
theological differences
History
Culture
Size

Human failure
What I mean is: The Bible/Jesus preaches peace and love, yet humans fail the most important rule in Matthew 22:37-40:

36 “Teacher, which is the great commandment in the Law?” 37 And he
said to him, “You shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and
with all your soul and with all your mind. 38 This is the great and
first commandment. 39 And a second is like it: You shall love your
neighbor as yourself. 40 On these two commandments depend all the Law
and the Prophets.”

Meaning, that Christians failed to resolve their conflicts and therefore split. If splitting were the only thing I wouldn't actually see that as that big of a problem but since Christians fought each other in the Name of God, makes it embarrassing unfortunately. However, the Bible also teaches that sin is part of humanity and not every Christian is "really" Christian and likes to gain the power that comes with leading positions in the Church.
Also, people can introduce false doctrines that still convince enough people and come into conflict with the right one.
theological differences
Sometimes people disagree on theological doctrines. There are a lot of theological debates to choose from, but I think one of the more well-known ones would be Luther's objection to the Sale of indulgences by the catholic church.
Basically, the catholic church sold papers that would reduce the amount of punishment a person would serve after dying, while Luther said that the sacrifice of Jesus on the cross is enough for a person to be freed of sin.
My opinion on theological differences is that many differences should not warrant a split. E.g. I would argue that whether the wine at the communion symbolizes the Blood of Jesus or really becomes the Blood of Jesus, shouldn't trump the most important rule in Matthew 22:37-40, meaning the debate should be done in love and shouldn't be a reason to split and harass others.
History & Culture & Size
Well, there are many denominations because Christianity spread all over the globe reaching Millions of people throughout history.
With that many people, the number of differences increases a lot which might warrant a split. Also, Culture can play a big role in how a person would act out their faith or what a person prioritizes.
As a European Christian, I notice quite a lot of differences between Church culture in Europe vs. Africa. These differences aren't "bad" but are enough that I would prefer a European style of church service in the long run, without condemning the African style.
However, I wish and pray that the denominations put behind their differences, present a united front, and cooperate more with each other.

Thank you for your answer! I understand, but isn’t this a serious issue since as Jesus Himself says in John 3:3 and John 14:6, there is only one way to heaven, and since the majority of Christian denominations teach differently, many are still condemned to an eternity in hell?

@SallyK Yes. Good question! 2 Cor 4:1-4 "Therefore seeing we have this ministry, as we have received mercy, we faint not; 2 But have renounced the hidden things of dishonesty, not walking in craftiness, nor handling the word of God deceitfully; but by manifestation of the truth commending ourselves to every man's conscience in the sight of God. 3 But if our gospel be hid, it is hid to them that are lost: 4 In whom the god of this world hath blinded the minds of them which believe not, lest the light of the glorious gospel of Christ, who is the image of God, should shine unto them."

@SallyK Well I agree it is, but on the other hand, let's not forget about the consensus that the denominations also have. The consensus is that God in his Trinity exists created the earth, revealed himself through the Bible and Jesus died on the cross for our sins. So if you are concerned about your salvation: Read and follow the Bible, repent your sins, baptize, declare your faith, and follow Matthew 22:37-40. Also just as you're quoting John 14:6: Through Jesus you get into heaven and not the church. Doesn't make the Church unimportant but ultimately God is the Judge, not the church.

Actually, having faith alone in Christ alone is the requirement. Not sinning, being water baptized, following Christ's earthly ministry to Israel, etc... will only keep a lost soul lost.  Those are all things that man can take credit for (boast about).  Rather, thank God for the forgiveness of sin that He gave the world on the cross. Thank God for our one and only baptism which is into Christ's body by the Spirit Himself upon having faith in Him.  Thank God for completing all the work required for us. Now saved by faith in this, remove sin from your life because of His gift...not for it.

So here we can see live such a theological difference :). @MarkVestal "Not sinning, being water baptized, following Christ's earthly ministry to Israel," Except for baptism this is not what I said. I said "repenting" sin and "follow the Bible in particular Mathew 22:37-40 meaning following God as well as loving your neighbor". I didn't say anything about ministries or not ever sinning again.

Also, Baptism is a topic with many positions of which I find most acceptable in their theological framework.  In general, you should baptize when you want to follow God, but I concede there are possible exceptions that allow unbaptized people into heaven.

No longer sinning is what is implied from telling someone to "repent". However, we will not be judged by how well we removed sin from our lives.  Jesus Christ was judged in full for all of our sins today.
Regarding baptism, there is only 1 that matters and it is performed by the Spirit. Eph 4:5 "One Lord, one faith, one baptism," ...Even Peter agrees, it is not the baptism of water: 1 Peter 3:21
"The like figure whereunto even baptism doth also now save us (not the putting away of the filth of the flesh, but the answer of a good conscience toward God,) by the resurrection of Jesus Christ:"

Why are there so many denominations? The Ultimate Desire It is evident from 1 Corinthians 1:10-17 that divisions among the brothers was frowned upon. It seems that personalities caused splits. People ran after famous or important figures at the expense of "unity among the brethren."
And Jesus had previously placed an emphasis on all the brothers showing love "one to another," and being in "perfect unity". (John 17:23)
Rise of Denominations (and Christian religions?) However in time the history of the Christian Church has demonstrated a tendency to divide into sects. It should be noted that tome of these splits are reasonable. As the Christian Church (Kingdom of God) spread throughout the earth it encompassed people of many different nationalities, cultures, languages. Since birds of a feather flock together it was only natural that local churches of the same races would congregate together, separate from local churches of another race.  Customs in music, food, fashion, etc. were different and would not be comfortable in different settings.
For example most of the people in the western Mediteranian spoke Latin, while those living in the East spoke Greek. The split was obvious. The music of the northern tribes in Europe was quite different from the African peoples, so worship was also of a different style and division was expected.
Apostles Creed Along with these aspects, there were also doctrinal and theological differences. Small details in syntax (Greek koine) led to differences of opinion. And occasionally synods (conferences of bishops) were held to iron out differences. While General Creeds were formulated, there were always some who did not agree with the findings. Hence denominations or "branches" of Christianity were formed.
It should be noted that the majority of the statements in the Creeds were acceptable to all. They contained the basics of Christianity. There was a saying that became predominant: In essentials unity, in non-essentials, tolerance, and in all things, charity!
Protestantism When the Reformation happened and the Reformed churches (Calvinism, Lutheranism, Hugenots, Moravians, etc.) began to form Protestantism,  the Christian Church moved north and west, even across the Atlantic! These local churches saw different aspects of traditional Christianity that need changing, and so they formed denominations emphasizing those issues. Theological differences abounded as well.
But in all of this history of Protestantism, most agreed on the basics found in the Apostles Creed. The essentials of Christianity were agreed upon...the devil was in the details! The essential beliefs for "salvation" are the same.(Romans 3:212-28)
Modern Denominations There are still many nuances of the Christian faith that local pastors love to discuss...many passages that are interpreted differently by different congregations.
However, these local congregations realize that in order to fulfill many of the "ministries of Christianity" they must come together and pool their resources. One local church, for instance, could not afford to establish a Bible College or Seminary for training ministers. But a conglomerate, together in forming a "Denomination", could be able to do just that.
A denomination (group of churches) could also fund and run orphanages...hospitals...old folks homes...retirement pensions for ministers...printing presses for Bibles...organized Sunday Schools...etc. These would all be impossible if just one local church had a vision for them.
It should be noted that in emergency situations, or in times of tragedy, these various Christian denominations do pull together, pool their resources and man-power ,and work together to rescue the needy! Unity is manifest in charity.
Freedom An important feature in all of this must not be overlooked: freedom. The reason that local churches can do theological research---and come up with varying conclusions---is because of the generally accepted concept of freedom. Believers are allowed to hold sincerely held beliefs in Protestantism, and form local churches at will.
As an aside: One of the great founders of American democracy, Thomas Jefferson, saw the benefit of congregationalism manifest in the local Baptist (Congregational) churches, and let this influence his role in establishing American democracy!  Freedom, with the people who had a say, was manifest and it was exhilarating. This "religious freedom" has been a magnet for people from all nations to cause them to want to immigrate to the United States.

Also a good answer. Forgot about languages in mine.

The primary cause of the creation of the vast number of man-made denominations in Christianity can be attributed to the neglecting of how we are to study scripture as admonished in a single verse:
2 Timothy 2:15

Study to shew thyself approved unto God, a workman that needeth not to be ashamed, rightly dividing the word of truth.

We should not be ashamed to recognize and respect the various groups of believers in the Bible, the various doctrines given, and the various purposes each have whether on earth (Israel) or in heaven (us, the body of Christ).
Ephesians 1:10

That in the dispensation of the fulness of times he might gather together in one all things in Christ, both which are in heaven, and which are on earth; even in him:

Contention began between Peter's church of believing Jews at Pentecost and Paul's church of believing Gentiles, the body of Christ, before the Bible could even be completed due to the misappropriation of biblical doctrine.
Galatians 2:1-9

Then fourteen years after I went up again to Jerusalem with Barnabas, and took Titus with me also.
2 And I went up by revelation, and communicated unto them that gospel which I preach among the Gentiles, but privately to them which were of reputation, lest by any means I should run, or had run, in vain.
3 But neither Titus, who was with me, being a Greek, was compelled to be circumcised:
4 And that because of false brethren unawares brought in, who came in privily to spy out our liberty which we have in Christ Jesus, that they might bring us into bondage:
5 To whom we gave place by subjection, no, not for an hour; that the truth of the gospel might continue with you.
6 But of these who seemed to be somewhat, (whatsoever they were, it maketh no matter to me: God accepteth no man's person:) for they who seemed to be somewhat in conference added nothing to me:
7 But contrariwise, when they saw that the gospel of the uncircumcision was committed unto me, as the gospel of the circumcision was unto Peter;
8 (For he that wrought effectually in Peter to the apostleship of the circumcision, the same was mighty in me toward the Gentiles:)
9 And when James, Cephas, and John, who seemed to be pillars, perceived the grace that was given unto me, they gave to me and Barnabas the right hands of fellowship; that we should go unto the heathen, and they unto the circumcision.

Jewish doctrine was being presented to new Gentile believers as a requirement to be a "Christian", but Paul is forced to defend the "freedom" from these religious acts due to the new completeness a believer has been gifted through placing one's faith in the finished work of that of Jesus Christ alone.
Colossians 2:6-15

As ye have therefore received Christ Jesus the Lord, so walk ye in him:
7 Rooted and built up in him, and stablished in the faith, as ye have been taught, abounding therein with thanksgiving.
8 Beware lest any man spoil you through philosophy and vain deceit, after the tradition of men, after the rudiments of the world, and not after Christ.
9 For in him dwelleth all the fulness of the Godhead bodily.
10 And ye are complete in him, which is the head of all principality and power:
11 In whom also ye are circumcised with the circumcision made without hands, in putting off the body of the sins of the flesh by the circumcision of Christ:
12 Buried with him in baptism, wherein also ye are risen with him through the faith of the operation of God, who hath raised him from the dead.
13 And you, being dead in your sins and the uncircumcision of your flesh, hath he quickened together with him, having forgiven you all trespasses;
14 Blotting out the handwriting of ordinances that was against us, which was contrary to us, and took it out of the way, nailing it to his cross;
15 And having spoiled principalities and powers, he made a shew of them openly, triumphing over them in it.

Paul questions the believers in his churches as to why they have allowed old religious doctrine to re-emerge after having been set free from that "yoke of bondage" and thus fallen from that freedom from religion made available by God's grace.
Galatians 3:1-10

O foolish Galatians, who hath bewitched you, that ye should not obey the truth, before whose eyes Jesus Christ hath been evidently set forth, crucified among you?
2 This only would I learn of you, Received ye the Spirit by the works of the law, or by the hearing of faith?
3 Are ye so foolish? having begun in the Spirit, are ye now made perfect by the flesh?
4 Have ye suffered so many things in vain? if it be yet in vain.
5 He therefore that ministereth to you the Spirit, and worketh miracles among you, doeth he it by the works of the law, or by the hearing of faith?
6 Even as Abraham believed God, and it was accounted to him for righteousness.
7 Know ye therefore that they which are of faith, the same are the children of Abraham.

Galatians 5:1-6

Stand fast therefore in the liberty wherewith Christ hath made us free, and be not entangled again with the yoke of bondage.
2 Behold, I Paul say unto you, that if ye be circumcised, Christ shall profit you nothing.
3 For I testify again to every man that is circumcised, that he is a debtor to do the whole law.
4 Christ is become of no effect unto you, whosoever of you are justified by the law; ye are fallen from grace.
5 For we through the Spirit wait for the hope of righteousness by faith.
6 For in Jesus Christ neither circumcision availeth any thing, nor uncircumcision; but faith which worketh by love.

The major concern with religion that Paul warns us of is that in our effort to establish our own self-righteousness, we fail to submit to the righteousness of God.
Romans 10:1-4

Brethren, my heart's desire and prayer to God for Israel is, that they might be saved.
2 For I bear them record that they have a zeal of God, but not according to knowledge.
3 For they being ignorant of God's righteousness, and going about to establish their own righteousness, have not submitted themselves unto the righteousness of God.
4 For Christ is the end of the law for righteousness to every one that believeth.

Paul is clear that we should not allow doctrines of man through religion to be our guide in the perfecting of our new spiritual identities in Christ.
Ephesians 4:12-15

For the perfecting of the saints, for the work of the ministry, for the edifying of the body of Christ:
13 Till we all come in the unity of the faith, and of the knowledge of the Son of God, unto a perfect man, unto the measure of the stature of the fulness of Christ:
14 That we henceforth be no more children, tossed to and fro, and carried about with every wind of doctrine, by the sleight of men, and cunning craftiness, whereby they lie in wait to deceive;
15 But speaking the truth in love, may grow up into him in all things, which is the head, even Christ:

It was by our faith alone in Christ that we were made a new spiritual creation and now perfect and justified before God through our faith alone, not by any of our own efforts found in religious works.
2 Corinthians 5:16-21

Wherefore henceforth know we no man after the flesh: yea, though we have known Christ after the flesh, yet now henceforth know we him no more.
17 Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new.
18 And all things are of God, who hath reconciled us to himself by Jesus Christ, and hath given to us the ministry of reconciliation;
19 To wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation.
20 Now then we are ambassadors for Christ, as though God did beseech you by us: we pray you in Christ's stead, be ye reconciled to God.
21 For he hath made him to be sin for us, who knew no sin; that we might be made the righteousness of God in him.

Just as it was imputed to Abraham, the righteousness of God is also gifted to us upon having faith alone.
Romans 4:20-25

He staggered not at the promise of God through unbelief; but was strong in faith, giving glory to God;
21 And being fully persuaded that, what he had promised, he was able also to perform.
22 And therefore it was imputed to him for righteousness.
23 Now it was not written for his sake alone, that it was imputed to him;
24 But for us also, to whom it shall be imputed, if we believe on him that raised up Jesus our Lord from the dead;
25 Who was delivered for our offences, and was raised again for our justification.


You make it sound like it only people read the Bible properly there'd be no denominations. This is far too simplistic. And you also didn't give an explanation for the thousands of Protestant denominations which all agree with that explanation of the Gospel.

@curiousdannii The point is not to offend, it is to free. 2 Corinthians 11:3 "But I fear, lest by any means, as the serpent beguiled Eve through his subtilty, so your minds should be corrupted from the simplicity that is in Christ." Galatians 4:16 "Am I therefore become your enemy, because I tell you the truth?"
